# Setting textAlignment doesn't fully right align UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have some `UITableViewCell`s and I want each of them to have two labels: one left aligned, one right aligned. The problem I'm having is that the right-aligned labels come very close but still not quite properly aligned. To be honest, I'm not entirely sure if I've even implemented it the correct way.

Here's a screenshot:
[(a link because I need 10 rep to embed images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u45Ss.png)

Here's my tableView function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    var secondLabel = UILabel(frame: cell.frame)
    secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    secondLabel.text = "Label \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.textLabel?.addSubview(secondLabel)

    return cell
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What constraints do you have on  secondLabel? I don't think the problem is with text alignment, it's with how you're placing the label.

Comment: Adding subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath is not a good idea by the way. Use a prototype or subclass UITableViewCell with a .xib file, and add your UI elements there. The way you have it, the label you are adding will be there when the cell dequeues and a new one will allocated and added as well.

Comment: Set a another color to secondLabel background color. It may help points out what could be the issue (constraints, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by following Dreaming in Binary's suggestion and making a xib file and adding constraints via the interface builder. I wasn't adding any constraints to the cell previously, so I guess it was a constraint problem.